# Can I use cork underlayment as a bulletin board?

Tags: cork

I want to make a full wall cork board, to pin things to. It seems like the easiest way to do that is using a roll of ¼" underlayment, but I want to make sure there's not a reason this is actually a terrible idea.

Will cork underlayment work as a cork board?

And should I glue it?

EDITED TO ADD: I was worrying that somehow underlayment is so different that you couldn't put a pin into it. That there is maybe something different about the density of underlayment.

Comment: How thick is the cork on the cork boards sold at your local big-box store? Probably not significantly more than the 1/4" you're looking at using. If you decide that it's not thick enough, it's probably cheap enough to add another layer! Should you glue it? Well, if you're never planning on removing it, go for it! Just be aware that any glue that'll hold it will pull drywall and probably plaster apart when you take it off.

Comment: Reminds of turning an entire wall into a whiteboard [(this is an example, never used it, but so you know what I'm referring to)](https://www.remarkablecoating.com/), which if I remember correctly was a plot point in a strange science fiction book I read a few years ago.

Answer (score 3):

No reason that it could not be a bulletin board.

Should you glue it?  That depends on far too many factors but the most important is the question...How do you feal about having to remove the glue when you no longer want the cork there?

Perhaps it would be better to glue the cork to a board and hang the board where you need it.